# How to test if a url provided points to a valid WSDL

Tags: c#, wsdl

I have the code below that does a URL test to see if it points to a valid wsdl that can be read.

However, I would prefer not to do this test with a try catch and would rather use a more appropriate call that would return a indicator stating whether it is a valid URL or not.

Here is the code I'm currently using:

```
class TestProgram
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        bool test = IsValid_WSDL_URL("http://notValid:888/test?wsdl");
    }

    public static bool IsValid_WSDL_URL(string url)
    {
        using (var webClient = new System.Net.WebClient())
        {
            try
            {
                webClient.OpenRead(url);
                return true;
            }
            catch
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean with 'valid' ? Listening for clients ? or specific response ? In your sample code, you just test, wether the webserver is dead or not.

Comment: Hi, yes, basically I want to know if the webservice is alive at the url provided without having to use a try catch

Answer (score 0):

Add timeout to your webclient, otherwise will take very long time for timeout:

```
private class MyWebClient : WebClient
{
    protected override WebRequest GetWebRequest(Uri uri)
    {
        WebRequest w = base.GetWebRequest(uri);
        w.Timeout = 3000;  // 3 seconds
        return w;
    }
}
```